# Unable to access System.Linq even though System.Core.dll is included

Tags: c#, linq, dll, .net-4.7.2

I have this console app:

```
namespace LinqTestFramework
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                { 1, "David" }
            };            
        } //breakpoint set here: Watch window: System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(dict, x => true)
    }
}

namespace LinqTestFramework
{
    using System.Linq;
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            var valuesBelowFour = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where(x => x < 4);
        }        
    }
}
```

I can see from ILSpy that the System.Core dll which contains those methods has been included:

[image]

I'm trying to run the following during debug from the Watch window:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(dict, x => true)
```

But I'm getting this error:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the
> namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Why am I unable to access the extension methods in `System.Linq.Enumerable`?

Comment: What .net Version are you using? If i am correct, there was a Bug with that in .net core 2.x

Comment: @Jodn .NET Framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it needs a method call which uses Linq method to load it. So I tried below code and now it is working

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
            {
                { 1, "David" }
            };
            
           var n = dict.Keys.Select(x=>x);

        } //breakpoint set here: Watch window: 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'm looking for an answer to why this happens, not a fix.

Comment: Check the Debug>Modules. Without LINQ method call, it is not loading debug symbol for System.Linq.dll.